# I'm trying to create an enum but I get "identifier expected error"

Tags: c++, enums, mql4, mql5

I have this code:

```
    enum EXECUTION_COMMANDS {
   "buy" = OP_BUY,
   "sell" = OP_SELL,
   "buyLimit" = OP_BUYLIMIT,
   "sellLimit" = OP_SELLLIMIT,
   "buyStop" = OP_BUYSTOP,
   "sellStop" = OP_SELLSTOP
};
```

So basically what I want to create is when program sees the string "buy", it has to read it as OP_BUY. Since OP_BUY is an internal command on MQL4, how do I do this? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: The keys in an enum should be identifiers, not strings.

Comment: Okay. But how we go about this? Since if i type buy instead of "buy", am I able to do the thing I want to do?

Comment: @blennd What is it you actually want to do exactly? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 4):

```
enum EXECUTION_COMMANDS
{
    buy = OP_BUY,
    ...
};
```

Now the identifier `buy` is basically a named integer constant with the same value as `OP_BUY`. You can use `buy` and `OP_BUY` as aliases for each other.

---

If you really want to use *strings* then you need to create a map, that maps the strings into their integer values:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> command_map = {
    { "buy", OP_BUY },
    ...
};
```

Then to use it use `command_map["buy"]` which will return the `int` value of `OP_BUY`.

Answer (score 1):

Just take out the quotes.

The names of the enumerators should be identifiers, not strings.

```
enum EXECUTION_COMMANDS
{
   buy       = OP_BUY,
   sell      = OP_SELL,
   buyLimit  = OP_BUYLIMIT,
   sellLimit = OP_SELLLIMIT,
   buyStop   = OP_BUYSTOP,
   sellStop  = OP_SELLSTOP
};
```

But if you wanted this to replace actual string literals in your source code, you're going to be disappointed. Either do not use string literals or, if you can't change the input being strings, introduce some mapping using a `std::map<std::string, int>`.